# Medicine search

Tags: english, quote

So, I have been suffering from something which I have no idea about. I only know that I am not well. Thus, I visited a doctor who examined me and wrote something on a piece of paper.

I took the paper to the doctor's friend who was a chemist and had his shop nearby. He was about to give me the medicine when I stopped him. I asked him, what the doctor had written on the piece of paper. He smiled and handed me the piece of paper and asked me to try and solve it. The doctor's handwriting allowed me to decipher only a fragment of what was truly written.

> "tsthlnwrkrwhmksthfrstdvncnsbjct."

All of this made zero sense to me. Can you guys find out which medicine I was prescribed by the doctor??

---

<sub>(inspired by @IAminPLS post)</sub>

Comment: That's more intelligible than any prescription my doctors have ever written...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> [Penicillin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_penicillin)

Because the text on the paper truly reads:

> *It is the lone worker who makes the first advance in a subject* - [Alexander Fleming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Fleming), who discovered Penicillin.

Explanation

> All the vowels (and spaces) have been removed. 
> **I**t **i**s th**e** l**o**n**e** w**o**rk**e**r wh**o** m**a**k**e**s th**e** f**i**rst **a**dv**a**nc**e** **i**n **a** s**u**bj**e**ct

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: @ajrthegreat I immediately noticed that the vowels were missing, After some time, I got the first five words correctly (also the last one), then I just googled what I've got + "quote" and checked if the quote matches. Still not sure how to determine the medicine, though.

Comment: Wow, amazing... I am impressed! and I would of thought its his most famous invention :)

Comment: What did fleming do??

Comment: @ajrthegreat And I find my ignorance and the fact that I didn't bother to google his name amazing... Thanks for the reminder :P

Comment: You did the hard work ;)

Comment: I should have made the quote longer...